# Navigation drawer and sliding panel in the same activity

Tags: android

I need to use navigation drawer for left side menu and sliding panel for right side menu. Is any option to use them together, on same layout? 
I have following layout for my activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/side_menu_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/oliveGreen"/>
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="@color/gray"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and navigation drawer (obviously) works but I cannot figure out how to add sliding panel. 
Any advice would be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
This is what I want to achieve: 
[image]

Comment: Do one thing, when u add  any fragment by nav drawer insert sliding layout in that fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Add another child View/ViewGroup inside `DrawerLayout` with `layout_gravity` set to `end` - this will act as your sliding panel.

Try code below, sliding panel is another `ListView` in this case but you can use `<fragment />` or `<LinearLayout />` etc instead:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/side_menu_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/oliveGreen"/>

    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="@color/gray"/>

    <ListView android:id="@+id/sliding_panel"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="@color/gray"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: It will act like another navigation drawer. The case is that I need to use sliding panel.

Comment: Please could you be more precise? It should be like sliding up panel? What is expected behaviour?

Comment: To be more specific: I need navigation drawer (left side menu), and on the right side sliding panel. Your solution would work for me if the navigation drawer on the right side could be partially visible (margin or something) to let user know that there's another menu. Please see my edited question.